# Unexpected token "name" of value "join" ("end of print statement" expected)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have this piece of code in a Twig template:

```
{% block body_class %}{{ app.user.roles|default([])join('')|lower }}{% endblock %}
```

But I am getting the error below (same as title) while try to render the template:

> Unexpected token "name" of value "join" ("end of print statement" expected)

I have tried to debug the template in console by running `lint:twig` and this is the result:

```
  lint:twig ./app/Resources/

  ERROR  in ./app/Resources//views/easy_admin/layout.html.twig (line 4)
      2      {% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/layout.html.twig' %}
      3
  >>  4      {% block body_class %}{{ app.user.roles|default([])join('')|lower }}{% endblock %}
  >> Unexpected token "name" of value "join" ("end of print statement" expected).
      5

 [WARNING] 5 Twig files have valid syntax and 1 contain errors.
```

But I am not sure what could be wrong there, can any give me some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
{{ app.user.roles|default([])|join('')|lower }}
```

Because `join` is a filter.